Working with gradients in tensorflow and keras
I am working on an AI NLP model that classifies text in 6 categories. I can't disclose the specific purpose of the model, sorry. Here it is: -
Input = keras.layers.Input((1368, ))
embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(1386, 50)(Input)

# The model will have two branches, in one we will be using 1D convents, on the other we will be using RNNs.

# The convent part
convent_1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 10, activation = "relu")(embedding)
convent_2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 7, activation = "relu")(convent_1)
convent_3 = keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation = "relu")(convent_2)
maxpool_1 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D(2)(convent_3)
maxpool_2 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D(2)(maxpool_1)
flatten_1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(maxpool_2)
reducing_size_dense = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(flatten_1) # To match the size of the flatten layer of rnn part.

# The RNN part
rnn_1 = keras.layers.GRU(128, activation = "relu", return_sequences = True)(embedding)
rnn_2 = keras.layers.GRU(128, activation = "relu", return_sequences = False)(rnn_1)
flatten_2 = keras.layers.Flatten()(rnn_2)

# The classifier
sum_flatten = keras.layers.Add()([reducing_size_dense, flatten_2])
dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(sum_flatten)
dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(dense_1)
dense_3 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(dense_2)
dense_4 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(dense_3)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = "softmax")(dense_4)
# We are using kappa quadratic loss function. Therefore we will have to take the argmax of the output layer. 
# Defining the argmax layer

class Argmax_layer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def call(self, input): # Keras layers are called by the call method.
        return (tf.argmax(input, axis = -1) + 1) # We have to add 1 because the indices are in the range 0-5. We want them to be in the range 1-6.

argmax_layer = Argmax_layer()(output_layer)


model = keras.Model(Input, argmax_layer)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)


It is a keras model as described in the question. The problem is occuring when I implement training: -
callback_list = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_accuracy", patience = 10),
                 keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(monitor = "val_accuracy", save_best_only = True, filepath = "scoring_model.keras"),
                 keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = "val_accuracy", patience = 5, factor = 0.25)]

model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = kappa_weighted_quad_loss, metrics = ["accuracy"])
history_model = model.fit(training_data, training_targets, validation_data = (validation_data, validation_targets), epochs = 100, callbacks = callback_list, batch_size = 20)
plot = dm.plotter(history = history_model.history)
plot.plot_loss()
plot.plot_acc()

Note that dm.plot_acc() and dm.plot_loss() are methods from my personal that helps me to preprocess data and manage AI models. I usually begin with these naive methods and then gradually tend to tensorboard.
You can see that I have implemented a custom loss function. Here is the loss function: -

# The evaluation of the result uses the weighted kappa, thus we will be defining that loss function.
def kappa_weighted_quad_loss(targets, preds):

    targets = targets - 1 # Because the targets and preds will be int he range 1-6, we will reduce 1 from each element and bring it to the range 0-5
    preds = preds - 1

    targets = tf.cast(targets, tf.int16)
    preds = tf.cast(preds, tf.int16)

    confusion_matrix = np.zeros(shape = (6, 6))
    for i, j in zip(targets, preds):
        confusion_matrix[i, j] += 1

    w_i_j = lambda i, j: (i - j)**2/25 # There are 6 categories so N = 6 and N - 1 = 5
    O_i_dot = lambda i: np.sum(confusion_matrix[i, :])
    O_dot_j = lambda j: np.sum(confusion_matrix[:, j])
    E_i_j = lambda i, j: np.outer(O_i_dot(i) , O_dot_j(j)) / np.sum(confusion_matrix)

    numerator = np.sum([w_i_j(i, j) * confusion_matrix[i, j] for i in range(6) for j in range(6)])
    denominator = np.sum([w_i_j(i, j) * E_i_j(i , j) for i in range(6) for j in range(6)])
    return 1 - numerator/denominator

It is the Cohen's weighted kappa loss for multi-class classification. What I am facing is this error while working on a GPU: -
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[41], line 6
      1 callback_list = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_accuracy", patience = 10),
      2                  keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(monitor = "val_accuracy", save_best_only = True, filepath = "scoring_model.keras"),
      3                  keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = "val_accuracy", patience = 5, factor = 0.25)]
      5 model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = kappa_weighted_quad_loss, metrics = ["accuracy"])
----> 6 history_model = model.fit(training_data, training_targets, validation_data = (validation_data, validation_targets), epochs = 100, callbacks = callback_list, batch_size = 20)
      7 plot = dm.plotter(history = history_model.history)
      8 plot.plot_loss()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py:662, in BaseOptimizer._filter_empty_gradients(self, grads, vars)
    659         missing_grad_vars.append(v.name)
    661 if not filtered_grads:
--> 662     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable.")
    663 if missing_grad_vars:
    664     warnings.warn(
    665         "Gradients do not exist for variables "
    666         f"{list(reversed(missing_grad_vars))} when minimizing the loss."
    667         " If using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a "
    668         "`loss` argument?"
    669     )

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable.

Where I can't guess prorperly the reason of this error, but it seems that tensorflow is unable to calculate the gradients with tf.GradientTape and other gradient measuring techniques.
I think it is because of the discontinues Argmax_layer but I am not confident with this explanation. Is there a way to calculate the gradients manually or anything else?

Tensorflow does not know how to compute gradients of numpy functions in your loss.

Does this answer your question? All Gradient values calculated as "None" if using BCE loss manually

Try this as your loss ported to TensorFlow. I couldn't test it by reproducing your case but at worse it will point you along the right direction:
def kappa_weighted_quad_loss(targets, preds):

targets = targets - 1 # Because the targets and preds will be int he range 1-6, we will reduce 1 from each element and bring it to the range 0-5
preds = preds - 1

targets = tf.cast(targets, tf.int16)
preds = tf.cast(preds, tf.int16)

confusion_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(targets, preds,6)

w_i_j = lambda i, j: (i - j)**2/25 # There are 6 categories so N = 6 and N - 1 = 5
O_i_dot = tf.math.reduce_sum(confusion_matrix,axis=0)
O_dot_j = tf.math.reduce_sum(confusion_matrix,axis=1)
E_i_j = lambda i, j: tf.experimental.numpy.outer(O_i_dot(i) , O_dot_j(j)) / tf.math.reduce_sum(confusion_matrix)

numerator = tf.math.reduce_sum([w_i_j(i, j) * confusion_matrix[i, j] for i in range(6) for j in range(6)])
denominator = tf.math.reduce_sum([w_i_j(i, j) * E_i_j(i , j) for i in range(6) for j in range(6)])
return 1 - numerator/denominator


Actually I did some research and I got to know that it's important to use tensorflow methods described by you, and I modified my code accordingly. And it didn't solved the problem. Still, thank you for the answer.
